# Cannot restore scoped Angular 2 packages in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with an ASP.NET 4.x project. I created an Angular 2 application with a package.json that includes the new Angular 2 RC scoped packages (@angular/common, @angular/core, etc). When I use the right-click restore packages on this package.json file I get in the Output console:

```
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'angular/compiler' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'product-management'
```

Any ideas on how to restore these scoped packages in Visual Studio 2015? (I know how to npm install from the command line ... I'd like to know how to do it *without* using the command line.)

Comment: It happens because external web tools OPTIONS are point to wrong (outdated) NPM. Move so that it refers PATH.

Comment: I had faced this issue, this link helped me https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/03/19/customize-external-web-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference. I get the same error.

Comment: OK, spoke too soon. I exited VS 2015 and reopened the project and then it worked! Thanks!

Comment: How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: Now you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because external web tools OPTIONS are pointing to wrong (outdated) NPM. Move so that it refers PATH.

Please refer this link to [customize external web tools in VS 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/03/19/customize-external-web-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/)

Restart Visual Studio to make it working.

Comment: I'm on VS2015 with update 3, after changing the web tools OPTIONS it still not seems to be working for me. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: With VS 2015 U3, it has latest TypeScript 1.8.*. So don't really need to change OPTIONS. Also uninstall existing Nodejs and install latest

Comment: I have the latest of all. Typescript 2 beta and node js  6.x

Comment: Not sure how TS 2 beta will behave, its just released & I still need to check, please try out TS 1.8.*

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar issue, despite the fact of correct order in "external web tools".

Try changing the `npm` version in your `package.json` file for at least `3.0.0`. For me it worked.